# JavaFX - remove selected item from other comboboxes

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm currently creating a tool to file reports for different incidents.

In a first step the user selects every person that was part of the call (we have a crew of 26 people). In the next step every selected person is written into 6 different comboboxes, so that the user can select the driver and the commander of each vehicle (3 vehicles - commander and driver on each vehicle, therefore 6 comboboxes).

My problem is: I need to prevent that the same person is selected as driver on *every* vehicle or as driver *and* commander at the same time. So I tried to remove the selected person from every other combobox via a ChangeListener:

(one ChangeListener for every combobox, an example here)

```
inputDriverTruck42.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
            String toRemove = inputDriverTruck42.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            inputDriverCar19.getItems().remove(toRemove);
            inputDriverTruck33.getItems().remove(toRemove);
            inputCommanderCar19.getItems().remove(toRemove);
            inputCommanderTruck42.getItems().remove(toRemove);
            inputCommanderTruck33.getItems().remove(toRemove);
        }

});
```

That works fine so far but when the user changes his selection for the first combobox the previously removed item is obviously gone in every other combobox. Also, if the user selects every person in the first combobox one after another every other combobox is going to be empty after a while.

So I somehow need to refill the boxes based on the selected item of every combobox without losing the currently selected item or re-adding the selected item back into the list.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-add the removed item back in the lists from where you removed it when you select a new item in your initial ComboBox.

The item that you remove from the other lists is actually the item which is currently selected in your first ComboBox. When you select the other value in the same ComboBox, your previously selected value will be saved in the oldValue variable (in your case it's `Object t` in `public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1))`.

When you hit the change event of the ComboBox, you first remove a newly selected item from the other ComboBoxes, check if the previously selected item is in those ComboBoxes, if not, add it there.

Example:

```
        @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue)
    {
        List<ComboBox<String>> groupedComboBoxes = comboBoxesMap.get(this.comboBoxGroupName);

        groupedComboBoxes.stream().filter(comboBox -> !comboBox.equals(this.currentComboBox)).forEach(comboBox ->
        {
            comboBox.getItems().remove(newValue);

            if (oldValue != null && !comboBox.getItems().contains(oldValue))
                comboBox.getItems().add(oldValue);
        });
    }
```

where `groupedComboBoxes` is a list of grouped ComboBoxes in which we are gonna remove/add items, `this.currentComboBox` is a ComboBox that hit the change event signal.

So, for all other ComboBoxes I remove the selected value, check if this is the first select of the item (`oldValue != null`) or if I am reselecting. If it's the first select, then do nothing, so only removal will happen in other ComboBoxes. If it's not, then check if the previously item has been really removed from other ComboBoxes and if this is the case, re-add it back.

A drawback of this approach is that your lists in the ComboBoxes in which you are re-adding an item are going to become unsorted in case they have been initially sorted. But that's already another story...

Answer (score -2):

Which JDK version are you using? Did you check in latest JDKs?
I would suggest you to check your issue on JDK [8u151](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), [JDK 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html).